# Reference request : Grothendieck's topological space valued integral

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ho.history-overview, integration

As I am learning the different kind of Banach space valued integrals (Pettis, Bochner), I know that Grothendieck made a  "mémoire" in his youth about this topic, but I don't know if it is available somewhere on the internet, and I would like to gain some insight about the unity of these constructions by consulting this paper.

I checked the reference in Laurent Schwartz's autobiography ("Un mathématicien aux prises avec le siècle"), and I made a mistake, the article is "L'intégration à valeurs dans un groupe topologique".

Comment: is this what you're looking for? http://www.ime.usp.br/acervovirtual/textos/estrangeiros/grothendieck/produits_tensoriels_topologiques/files/produits_tensoriels_topologiques.pdf [Résumé de la théorie métrique des produits tensoriels topologiques] (1953) ?

Comment: Thank you M. Beenakker, but it's unfortunately not this article (I'm not sure that it was ever published, as Schwartz said that Dieudonné criticized this work because of its lack of utility, but it might be anyway available in an electronic form).

Comment: I understand; the Dieudonné incident is an interesting read --- http://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~leila.schneps/grothendieckcircle/Mathematics/chap3.pdf

Comment: Thank you for this link I didn't know that Leila Schneps had written about this incident too.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker This is off-topic, but is that LaTeXed copy of G's Resume linked to from someone's webpage? Or is it "samizdat"? :)

Comment: @Yemon this copy of G'resume seems official: http://www.ime.usp.br/acervovirtual/estrangeiros.php