# Integration with values in a topological vector space

Tags: integration, topological-vector-spaces

Is there a general theory of integration of functions with values in a topological vector space (not necessarily locally convex)?

Browsing through mathoverflow posts, I came across a discussion regarding Grothendieck's work on integration with values in a topological group *L'intégration à valeurs dans un groupe topologique*  ([Reference request : Grothendieck's topological space valued integral](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/191762/reference-request-grothendiecks-topological-space-valued-integral) ). Unfortunately the requested reference is never provided. Does anyone know of a rough sketch of the approach used?

Just to emphasize, I am interested in a general theory and not in notions such as the Bochner integral, or Gelfand-Pettis integral which use local convexity of the topological vector space.

Comment: A hint of the kind of negative things that can happen: it is routine to extend the Riemann integral to this situation but it can happen that a continous function, say on $[0,1]$, is not integrable.  The basic reason is that in a non locally convex space, convex combinations of small elements can be huge, and Riemann sums are just such combinations.

Comment: However, there was some work done on this topic, in particular for so-called locally bounded tvs‘s, about 50 years ago. I suggest you look up D. Voigt, B. Gramsch and L. Waelbroeck in suitable sources (MathSciNet, Zentralblatt, etc.).

Comment: @user131781: That's a good point. A reference I found http://www.numdam.org/article/PSMIR_1979___1_A3_0.pdf (Butković, D. On integration with respect to measures with values in arbitrary topological vector spaces. Glas. Mat. Ser. III 15(35) (1980), no. 1, 33–40.  ) This is along the lines of Gerald Edgar's answer. This could get me started in understanding these measures. But I am still looking for a direct answer to integrating vector-valued functions over real or complex measures rather than vector-valued measures.

Comment: That is exactly what is done by the authors I mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

One reference ...

*Sion, Maurice*, [**A theory of semigroup valued measures**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BFb0060133), Lecture Notes in Mathematics. 355. Berlin-Heidelberg-New York: Springer-Verlag. V, 140 p. DM 16.00; $ 6.60 (1973). [ZBL0312.28016](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0312.28016).

Comment: Thank you. I edited the question a bit to emphasize that I want the function to take values in a topological vector space (and the measure is real or complex-valued).

Comment: If $\mu$ is a real-valued measure, and we are doing an integral like $\int_A f\;d\mu$ where $f$ has values in a tvs $X$, then the set-function $A \mapsto \int_A f\;d\mu$ is a measure with values in $X$.  Thus, the theory of vector-valued integrals is related to the theory of vector-valued measures.

Comment: You are right. They are related. A theory of vector-valued integrals immediately leads to a theory of vector-valued measure. But it is hard for me to visualize the opposite direction, that is, if we have a theory of vector-valued measures, how do we recover a theory of integration of vector-valued functions? Is there a recipe for doing that? (It invokes a feeling of some type of Radon-Nikodym there but I can't quite put my finger to it.)

Comment: @TVS_integration The Radon-Nikodym theorem can fail already for Banach spaces, so there's no need to go as far as non-locally convex spaces for that. The Banach spaces for which it doesn't fail are said to have "the Radon-Nikodym property" and it can be related to all sorts of other things.